# Axios always return string and missing last two characters

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am facing a problem with axios post.

```
  public function viewAuthCheck(Request$request){


        return [ 'test' => 'hello!' ];
    }
```

my axios function

```
axios.post('/timetracking/settings/auth/check/user', {
                    auth_check:this.auth_check_list

                }).then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                });
```

and the output always returns string and missing last two characters

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

**first**

you should return as json like this:

```
return response()->json(['test'=>'hello!']);
```

and when you access it by `axios`

```
console.log(response.data.test);
```

Comment: i tried it also! it returns 'undefined'. I think there is something in my controller. After i ran npm install all the bugs keep coming. After a laravel update i needed to update all my packages. Maybe I should read the updates of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return response()->json(['test' => 'hello!'])`

Comment: Thanks for help but it still returns same result.

Comment: when you console.log try console.log(response.data.test)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I think the cause root is related to the config of the web server.
On the local (use Nginx), I got the same issue (only on Firefox).
On the staging (use apache), it works fine.